# Faster `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` when you have *lots* of groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create lists from a column of a DataFrame grouping by an index. To perform this task I:

1. Group by an index
2. Aggregate all the items in each group into a list

However, once the number of groups gets large, this operation becomes very slow. Here is an illustrative example.

First, **the data**:

```py
import random
import uuid

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
random.seed(42)

def make_df(nr_level_one: int = 1000, max_nr_paths: int = 10):
    level_one_values = np.arange(nr_level_one)
    count_paths = np.random.randint(1, max_nr_paths+1, size=nr_level_one)
    idx_one = np.repeat(level_one_values, count_paths)
    nr_obs = np.sum(count_paths)
    idx_two = np.arange(nr_obs)
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        zip(idx_one, idx_two), names=['one', 'two']
    )

    paths = [str(uuid.UUID(int=random.getrandbits(128))).replace('-', '/')
             for _ in range(nr_obs)]

    return pd.DataFrame(paths, index=idx, columns=['path'])

df = make_df()
df
```

```
        path
one two 
0   0   bdd640fb/0667/1ad1/1c80/317fa3b1799d
    1   23b8c1e9/3924/56de/3eb1/3b9046685257
    2   bd9c66b3/ad3c/2d6d/1a3d/1fa7bc8960a9
    3   972a8469/1641/9f82/8b9d/2434e465e150
    4   17fc695a/07a0/ca6e/0822/e8f36c031199
... ... ...
999 5443    fe66c4fa/35ed/ff38/9197/107c89b702ed
    5444    a560c775/58cf/d966/6f11/0436b3c28ec5
    5445    49e785c7/cbd8/715e/ae98/b722cf97b016
    5446    f7eefd84/b31c/8349/5799/2f42351b3e63
    5447    be3de265/d471/8d86/8d36/645980f6c26c
5448 rows × 1 columns
```

I want to aggregate all `path`s at level one in the index into a list. **This is the function which achieves what I want**:

```py
df.groupby(level='one').agg(list)
```

```
    path
one 
0   [bdd640fb/0667/1ad1/1c80/317fa3b1799d, 23b8c1e...
1   [6b65a6a4/8b81/48f6/b38a/088ca65ed389, 4737819...
2   [371ecd7b/27cd/8130/4722/9389571aa876, 1a2a73e...
3   [3139d32c/93cd/59bf/5c94/1cf0dc98d2c1, a9488d9...
4   [29a3b2e9/5d65/a441/d588/42dea2bc372f, ab9099a...
... ...
995 [5dc2fd9b/f1bd/b57b/b8dd/dfc2963ba31c, aa1c5dc...
996 [1e228ade/59c6/7a52/8f80/d1ef4615575c, d60b04a...
997 [f151ff15/a46e/e99e/ae4e/d89fd659d69f, bf5628b...
998 [17a85108/43b9/3b02/7089/8400b2932bfb, 5d15c12...
999 [85e620fe/a44e/b3e1/c5ba/136f594ed61a, afe1d84...
1000 rows × 1 columns
```

*But* as you scale up the number of groups, **this gets very very slow** (though it does seem to scale linearly with the number of groups)

```py
%%timeit
make_df(100000).groupby(level='one').agg(list)
```

```
15 s ± 230 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Is there a faster way of achieving the same task with pandas?**

Comment: Why are you renaming after grouping?

Comment: Not really necessary - i'll remove. The output is now a list is all.

Comment: Probably not... `pandas` doesn't deal well with storing complex objects, and you're likely seeing a consequence of that (the groupby becomes a slow loop over the groups, not something that has a fast path in cython or can be vectorized across the entire DataFrame). Why do you need those lists? Any subsequent manipulations are going to be very difficult. You already have the MultiIndex and I'd expect most other manipulations can be done efficiently given that organization. (Ofc if you need the list for some specific output, I think you're stuck)